# Avoid a promise to execute when created

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I do not want a promise to run before it is actually called by the script, but unfortunately a promise by default runs the moment it's created.

Is there a way to avoid this default execution of the code when the promise is created?

Comment: Create a function that calls it instead? Hard to say exactly without seeing the code

Comment: You should post some code, because it seems like the answer is don't execute that code, don't call it, until you want to. Store it in a variable or function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in a function that returns the promise, then call the promise later.

Set up your function which returns a promise:

```
function myAsyncFunction(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.reponse);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
    xhr.send();
    //  Or whatever you want in your function
  });
}
```

Then later, call your function:

```
 myAsyncFunction(url)
   .then( ... ) 
   .then( ... ) 
   .catch( ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

Promises don't "run".  An asynchronous notification runs when you call it and it returns a promise which is merely a notification scheme that the caller can use to understand when it's done and what it's result/error is.

It's not entirely clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but it sounds like you need to just not call your asynchronous operation until you want it to actually start executing.  For any more specific help, you'll have to show us your real code so we can see what you're trying to do and make a specific code recommendation.  It's also possible that you just need to wrap your code in a function which you can call sometime later.

> Is there a way to avoid this default execution of the code when the promise is created?

Don't call your asynchronous operation until you want it to start executing.

> unfortunately a promise by default runs the moment it's created.

Promises don't run.  Asynchronous operations run and use a promise to notify you of completion/results/error.  Asynchronous operations run when you execute them.  If you don't want them to execute yet, don't call them until you want them to run.